# OpenCV camera calibration using partial-frame images

Tags: opencv, camera, calibration, vision

I'm using an industrial camera which is capable of grabbing images with 2592x1944 pixels. To improve image processing speed, I'm setting an smaller AOI(area/region of interest), for example, a region of 2200x1400 pixel starting at 100,100, please note the center of AOI may not match the center of the full frame. Now I grab a few images of a chessboard pattern under this AOI setting and pass them to OpenCV functions findChessboardCorners and calibrateCamera. Can it recognize the real frame center and output the correct camera instrict parameters, for undistorting images under the same AOI setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I've learned about the camera calibration, is that you have to cover the whole frame meaning 2592x1944 to get a gut calibration, if you cropped you frame or change the resolution you'll get  wrong coordinates of the chessboard and  calculating the position of the the image plane need the full resolution size if you give the calibration function the wrong size you'll get a wrong calibration and if you the give it the right size with the wrong or just a part of the coverage you'll also get the wrong calibration! I hope that answer you question